# Can you play Fornite on PS4 without PlayStation Plus?

Tags: playstation-plus, fortnite-battle-royale

Can you play Fornite on PS4 without PlayStation Plus?

If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 7):

The majority of the time most online/multiplayer activity on PS4 games requires a Playstation Plus membership. Same thing applies for Xbox Gold membership for Xbox games.

But not always the case as the Battle Royale does NOT require PS Plus. [Source here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/71b8g2/fortnite_battle_royale_free_sept_26_faq/dn9mbdf/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You first need to download the game from PSNetwork Using your psn id just after installing game game will ask for a account sign-up for fortnite, that is the last thing you need to set up an account with the fortnite, have Fun :) yup I get that and it should be better if they could change and until you get game and then pay the guy can do it

Comment: Your answer's a bit late so I've already had 2 months of fun playing Fornite.

Answer (score -2):

You require only the system, a usable network, the app, and a PSN account.

Comment: You need the account for a few things but you do not have to make it.